# Using Multiple IP Addresses to stream content

Tags: ip-address, vpn

I want to preface this by saying I don't understand using proxys or VPNs or any of that stuff particularly well so I am apologizing in advance if my question isn't worded too clearly.

I was using some of the code found at this site https://medium.com/ml-book/multiple-proxy-servers-in-selenium-web-driver-python-4e856136199d to mask my IP address, similar to a VPN. The code provided at that site allows me to access a few (I'm assuming public?) proxy servers. However, when I open a browser window using the IP address and port provided by the above code it moves *very* slow. I was attempting to watch a twitch stream but it constantly had to buffer.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for other python packages or VPNs or software or whatever that would allow me to do this without slowing everything down by too much. My requirements are that I need to be able to have multiple browser windows open simultaneously, each having a unique IP address.

Answer (score 0):

My vpn client has a feature called split tunnelling, This allows certain application to run on my normal internet connection and others through my vpn.

I know this isn't an answer but may point you in the direction you are after, untill someone can give you better information.  I don't think this answers your question but I can not comment it i.